# 'ngx-avatar' is not a known element

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap, avatar

I'm facing these errors while using ngx-avatar

Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:

```
'ngx-avatar' is not a known element:

1. If 'ngx-avatar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ngx-avatar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

("

```
[ERROR ->]<ngx-avatar name="John Doe"></ngx-avatar>
```

"):

```
ng:///CardDetailsModule/CardDetailsComponent.html@118:6
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:2175)
    at TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:11388)
    at JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:25963)
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:25951)
    at compiler.js:25895
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:25895)
    at compiler.js:25808
    at Object.then (compiler.js:2166)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:25807)
```

I've included these in app.module.ts

```
import { AvatarModule } from 'ngx-avatar';
```

.
.
.

```
imports: [...,AvatarModule]
```

I have installed ngx globally, but it is still not working

Comment: Does the component in which the ngx-avatar added belongs to the app.module or it belongs to some other module?
If it belongs to some other module means to make sure you import the common module to that module you are using or you can directly import the AvatarModule in the module which you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are having two modules in your project

- App Module
- CardDetails Module

The **ngx-avatar** is used in the **cardsDetailComponent** which belongs to **CardDetails Module**. But you have imported the **ngx-avatar in app.module**.

Try to import the ngx-avatar module in **cardDetails.module** and check.Suppose if you are using the ngx-avatar across multiple modules means to move it to a **shared module** and import it to the modules where it requires

Once the ngx-avatar is imported to cardDetails.module make sure to delete it from **app.module**